# How to call a function of scriptB from scriptA

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have created two scripts one is `scrpt_Enemy` and other is `scrpt_GameManager`.

I want to call `SubtractLive()` function (exist on `scrpt_GameManager`) from `scrpt_Enemy`. But it gives error I don't know why. The error is  'SubtractLive' is not a member of 'UnityEngine.Component'.

**scrpt_Enemy:**

```
var gameManager : GameObject;
gameManager.GetComponent("scrpt_GameManager").SubtractLive();
```

**scrpt_GameManager:**

```
var lives : int =3;

function SubtractLive(){
    lives -= lives;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

You were telling Unity that `gameManager` was of type [GameObject](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html). Therefore Unity was freaking out because it doesn't have `SubtractLive()` under GameObject.

#### Solution

You can get the correct reference like this:

Create the variable then tell Unity what the type it is.

```
var gameManager : scrpt_GameManager;
```

Find the GameObject which has the script attach to it.

```
gameManager = GameObject.Find("GameManagerGameObject").GetComponent("scrpt_GameManager");
```

Note that "*GameManagerGameObject*" is the name of the GameManager in the scene.

Now that you have the reference to the script just call the function like this:

```
gameManager.SubtractLive();
```

Comment: Still Saying SubtractLive(); is not a member of 'UnityEngine.Component'.

Comment: I forgot something. You need this line: `var gameManager : scrpt_GameManager;` I have also included it in the answer above.